# What IDE for Android projects on Mac OS? Xcode or?

Tags: android, macos, ide

I'm thinking to begin Android app development. What's the better IDE?

Now I'm using Xcode for objective-C language, but I don't know if use it also for Java development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative is the [IntelliJ Idea IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) from jetbrains. If you like this IDE better you can use it, but the tools for developing Android apps are better in Eclipse, because they are more up to date.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) for Mac.

Comment: Just to add, XCode cannot be used.

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse is the best. It's supported by android team and they have an ADT plugin for eclipse

[ADT plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)